# Command executed in PHP with Centos7 and Apache isn't able to connect to network?

Tags: php, apache, shell, centos7, torque

I'm debugging my PHP app on CentOS7 using Apache. 
My application is a Web GUI to manage the Torque batch system and I used the `qmgr`, which is a command line tool provided by Torque to do the management work.

Because only the root user can execute the `qmgr` and the Apache server cannot be running as root user, I have written a C program as a wrapper for anyone to execute commands as root user.

But the PHP application always give the following output:

```
 socket_connect_unix failed: 15137
 qmgr: cannot connect to server  (errno=15137) could not connect to trqauthd
```

This means the PHP app cannot raise a socket connection to connect the Torque server.

Here is some additional information:

1. The command called by the PHP application can be executed correctly in the shell
2. The same PHP app can be executed correctly on a CentOS6 server with Apache
3. SELinux and the firewall are disabled
4. I have tried the two versions (5.1 and 4.10) of Torque, the result is the same
5. Apache and PHP are used  with the default RPM's of CentOS7.

I thought there are some new security limits that maybe influence Apache on the CentOS7 server.

Please give me some suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Is the curl installed ? And are the connection tried to connect on ipv4? Instead of the ipv6

Comment: You could see if there are any environment variables present on your CentOS6 box that aren't on your CentOS7 box. You could test this in Apache with the cgi-bin script printenv or you could find/develop a PHP version.

Comment: I have check all the env, and it's ok. I think this is not the reason to make the error

Comment: I have fix this problem! which is caused by the "/tmp" is denied to access in the Apach2.4 and is granted in the Apach2.2.

Comment: @chuchu can you explain your solution in detail?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem.

The cause is that newer Apache.httpd versions default to having the systemd property `PrivateTmp` set to true. This causes the httpd service to see a private /tmp directory that is actually mapped to some other location in the file system, instead of the real /tmp directory.  PHP, running in the Apache process, has the same /tmp directory as the Apache service, and so do any processes forked from PHP (e.g. using exec or system etc). So when PHP calls  qsub (etc), that too will see the private /tmp directory.

This causes the error you mentioned because qsub internally uses the unix socket `/tmp/trqauthd-unix` to communicate with trqauthd. But qsub sees the "fake"/private /tmp directory instead of the real one, so it doesn't find the socket.

This explains why the command works when you run it manually in a console--in that case, qsub sees the real /tmp directory, as opposed to the private one it sees when forked from PHP (running the Apache service).

One solution is to simply change the `PrivateTmp` property in the file `httpd.service` from true to false. You can find this file under the `/etc/systemd` directory. The subfolder it is in probably depends on the linux distribution, so use the `find` command to locate it:

```
find /etc/systemd -name httpd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

This really helped me!

I have been struggling a lot having a php script using exec()-command. For some reason I got permission denied. Having tried vary many things, including running my scripts in shell as the www-data user, but with no success, this was finally the solution to my problem.

BTW, for Ubuntu the apache service config file is located at cat /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service